# Approximating sum by Gaussian integral - how big is the error?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, approximation

I have the following infinite sum:

$$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{-an^2}$$

Where $a$ is a positive constant. Is there a simple way to estimate the error when approximating $S$ by:

$$S \approx \int_0^ \infty e^{-ax^2}dx .$$

Does this depend at all on the value of $a$?

Comment: Take a look at [Euler-Maclaurin Summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula).

Comment: I have, but it seems to me that it's bit too heavy of an artillery for this particular problem. I'm not looking for a very sharp bound, more of a justification for why this approximation is good.

Comment: @DepeHb: Since $e^{-a n^2}$ is decreasing very rapidly, you would get a much better approximation by summing finitely many terms instead of using the integral.

Comment: I should have pointed out that I'm interested in this approximation because it produces a nice compact formula as a function of $a$, which is of interest here, whereas summing finitely many terms wouldn't (I guess?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A *very simple* estimate (which is what you were asking for) would be the following:
$f(x) = e^{-a x^2}$ is strictly decreasing, therefore
$$
f(n+1) < \int_n^{n+1} f(x)\,dx < f(n)
$$
for all $n \in \mathbb N_0$. Summation gives
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n) < \int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx < f(0) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)
$$
So the difference between sum and integral is at most $f(0) = 1$.